# Put Share Button and Like Button on Same Line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my Facebook share button for a WP post on the same line as my FB like button for my page.

This is the code I'm using, but the Like button appears right below the share button, even though they're on the same line. I verified in FireFox's inspector that there's no width on either of them that would force them onto a new line.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you! (the brackets are shortcode for my plugin which won't let me use a php hard code)

```
[ultimatesocial_facebook]<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2MySite&amp;width&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80&amp;appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you have the blog's link? Anyway, maybe you don't have enough space in the line for the buttons to spread. We'd have to check this at the chrome inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to say, but I'm guessing that the `iframe` is being treated as a `block` element, instead of `inline`. Perhaps you could try adding `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` to the CSS being applied (you can drop it into the `style` attribute).